# Rails4 sort and paginate ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, unobtrusive-javascript

I am having trouble sorting lists on my app using ajax.

The pagination component works fine with ajax but the sorting component only works when I click it the first time. The second time it is clicked it does nothing. No errors are thrown but the app doesnt redirect to a new page nor it passes the sorting parameters to the controller.

Here are some relevant files:

Controller:

```
def show        
    @products_scope = Category.find(params[:id]).products.available.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
    @products = @products_scope.page(params[:page]).per(12)
end


private

    def sort_column
        %w[price updated_at].include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "updated_at"
    end

    def sort_direction
        %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc"
    end
```

ApplicationHelper:

```
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
     title ||= column.titleize
     direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
     link_to title, {:sort => column, :direction => direction}, :remote => true;
  end
```

Show.html.erb:

```
 <div id="sort-by-container" class=" sort-by-container  small-6 columns no-padding">
      <p class="sort-by title"> Sort by: </p>
      <p class="sort-by "><%= sortable "price" %></p>
      <p class="sort-by divider"> | </p>
      <p class="sort-by"><%= sortable "updated_at", "Newest" %> </p>
    </div>
  </div>  
        <div id= "paginator" class='row pagination-container'>
        <%= paginate @products, :remote => true %>
      </div>


      <div id= "products">
        <%= render @category %>
      </div>
```

show.js.erb:

```
+$('#products').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@category) %>');
+$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@products, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

UPDATE 1:
I think the problem might be coming from the direction variable in ApplicationHelper. When i try to debug the code I can see the get request but it always asks for ascending order. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what does "no working" exactly mean? Does clicking it the second time result in some kind of server exception or something? What happens exactly?

Comment: clicking it the second time does nothing. No errors are thrown.  The server throws a 200 so nothing has gone wrong. For some reason i think the params are not being passed because 'remote=>true'